# How can I check if a path is allowed in tauri.config allowList on Rust side before reads and writes of files?

Tags: rust, tauri

I have a tauri application that is reading and writing for example yaml files for the application configurations in the users machine. Initially I moved the implementation from frontend side of the application to the backend.

To get things working I used `std::fs::OpenOptions`to do the actual file manipulation and resolved the paths using [tauri::api::path](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/api/path/index.html).

This works but the problem is that this way the `allowList` scopes from tauri.config file is not respected, meaning that files could be created or read from any location, so how could I access the `allowList` scopes to check if path really is allowed there before opening files via `OpenOptions`?

I tried to see if the `tauri::api` exposes something for file manipulation on rust side that will respect the `allowlist` given in the configuration file, but did not find anything useful.

Also found this [FsScope](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/scope/struct.FsScope.html#) structure that seems to have `is_allowed` method, but not sure how to use it...

example from tauri.config.json

```
"tauri": {
  "allowList": {
    "fs": {
       "readFile": true,
       "writeFile": true,
       "readDir": true,
       "scope": ["$HOME/some_folder/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

so based on the tauri config file above, before accessing files I would like to check that given path to a file or directory is inside `$HOME/some_folder` and not pointing to anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_allowed` is indeed correct. To get access to it you need an instance of `App`, `AppHandle` or `Window`. If you use tauri commands it would look something like this:

```rs
use tauri::Manager;

#[tauri::command]
async fn(app_handle: tauri::AppHandle, path: PathBuf) {
    if app_handle.fs_scope().is_allowed(&path) {
        // Path is allowed.
    }
}
```